# php form multiple input

Tags: php, forms, input

I have a PHP page with a list of items pulled from a database. Each item has an input form next to it, and right at the bottom, a submit button.

How can i do a POST check to find out which inputs have had data added? I can get the data, but how do I know the names of the particular inputs that have been filled?

Comment: Show a snippet of your HTML and your current PHP code

Comment: " Each item has an input form next to it" Is it input form or input box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `$_POST` and list the keys which have nonempty values.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (!empty($value)) {
    echo $key . " was filled in.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the isset() function of PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

For Example,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['somevar'])) {
    // if the value has been set, this code is executed
} else {
 //value not set, so execute this code.

}
?>
```